# I don't think I'm using pointers correctly. C

Tags: c

So I've been trying to do this assignment for a few hours and I can't figure it out, I'm 99% sure it has to do with how I used the pointers. And the error I get is a break  0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.which I think means some of my pointers are null. Sorry for the amateur code in advance..

```
#include<stdio.h>

void load(int *salary)
{
    printf("Please enter your salary: ");
    scanf("%d", *salary);
}

void calc(int *salary, float *rate, int *raise, int *newsalary)
{
    rateofsalary(&salary);
    *raise = *salary/(*rate);
    *newsalary = *raise+*salary;
}
float rateofsalary(int *salary)
{
    float rate;
    if(*salary<0 && *salary>=30000)
        rate = 7.0;
    else 
        if(*salary<30000 && *salary>=40000)
            rate = 5.5;
        else 
            if(*salary<40000)
                rate = 4.0;
    return rate;
}

void print(int *salary, float *rate, int *raise, int *newsalary)
{
    printf("|     | Salary | Rate % | Raise | New Salary |\n");
    printf("|     | %d     | %0.2f  | %d    | %d         |\n", salary, rate, raise, newsalary);
}

void main()
{
    int salary, raise, newsalary;
    float rate;
    load(&salary);
    rateofsalary(&salary);
    calc(&salary, &rate, &raise, &newsalary);
    print(&salary, &rate, &raise, &newsalary);
}
```

Comment: `rateofsalary(&salary);` salary is already an `int*`, no need to get its reference

Comment: `rateofsalary(&salary);` should be `rate = rateofsalary(&salary);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", *salary);
```

change it to

```
scanf("%d", salary);
```

and the `printf` function should be

```
printf("|     | %d     | %0.2f  | %d    | %d         |\n", *salary, *rate, *raise, *newsalary);
```

Answer (score 1):

for the load function it should be

```
void load(int *salary)
{
    printf("Please enter your salary: ");
    scanf("%d", salary);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well in this line `scanf("%d", *salary);` instead of `*salary` just put `salary` so replace it with this `scanf("%d", salary);`

Answer (score 0):

In general, your problem is that you don't know when to quit :)

If something is of type `int *`, that means it's a pointer to an `int`, and it's not necessary nor correct to turn around and use `&` on it, which turns it into a pointer to pointer to int. You make this mistake multiple times, not only in the first short function as other answers have pointed out, but in multiple places. You manage to turn the variable `salary` from main into a pointer to pointer to pointer to int by the time you're through, adding a level of indirection each time you call another function.

Just keep track of what each function wants. If a function accepts an `int*` as an argument, and calls another function that wants an `int*`, then it can just pass the variable along as-is: you don't need to add a `&` to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are few places you use pointers wrong. What others didn't mention yet is:
in function:

```
void calc(int *salary, float *rate, int *raise, int *newsalary)
{
    rateofsalary(&salary);
    *raise = *salary/(*rate);
    *newsalary = *raise+*salary;
}
```

you call `rateofsalary` with `&salary`, which is `pointer to pointer to int`(int **), but formal argument of `rateofsalary` is declared as `int *` which is `pointer to int`.

It's not the best idea to variable by reference to function, that shouldn't be allowed to change that variable. Pass it by value or declare function parameter as `const`.
Whole idea of passing by reference is to be able to modify variable passed to function inside function body and you seem to be missing what pointers actually are or practical use of them.